# Meshlab smooth not saving in OBJ

Tags: 3d, scanning, meshlab

After I save as OBJ and then close and open up my file again in Meshlab, the smoothing filter I added is gone. It seems to be keeping some of the smaller smoothing changes but most of the object goes back to the way it was before I smoothed it. Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you paste the images of the smooth and previous mesh? Could you explain which smooth filter you used?

Comment: I used Laplacian Smoothing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your problem. Changes by Laplacian smoothing are correctly saved in my files. Maybe your problem is that you save the mesh without normal per vertex, so try to activate that flag in the export dialog.

Comment: `Smooth face normal` does not work, but `laplacian smoothing` works well.